# Gentzen's consistency proof of PA

Tags: logic, reference-request, peano-axioms

What would be some good introcutory references to start reading about Gentzen's consistency proof of Peano arithmetic?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you use the [tag:reference-request] tag.

Comment: Thank you, I've added it to the tags. I'll also mention that so far I've found an interesting exposition of the subject in Takeuti's "Proof theory", but am looking for something a bit more accessible.

Comment: [Proof Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory/) with biblio.

Comment: Annika Siders, [Gentzen’s consistency proof (2012)](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/~mizuhito/jss12/Siders.pdf)

Comment: Anna Horská, [Where is the Gödel-point hiding: Gentzen's consistency proof of 1936 and his representation of constructive ordinals, Springer (2014)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Where_is_the_G%C3%B6del_point_hiding_Gentzen/Iuq5BAAAQBAJ)